# Jasper Reports Pro library for Compile & Generating HTML5 reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

We have built our own reporting engine where we compile and fill jrxml's using Jasper Reports library.

Recently, we are planning to include HTML5 charts to our reports. Evaluated JasperStudio 6 professional and created a chart which uses highchart.

We need this jrxml containg highchart to be compiled and filled using jasper report library, but couldnt find any documentation where I can download jasperreport-pro jar files.

I installed JasperServer-pro and can see jasperreports-pro-6.0.0.jar in their WEB-INF/lib folder. But where can I download these libraries and use it standalone?

I went through https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jars-required-compile-simple-jrxml-html5-element which explains which jars are needed. But they say 'shipped with pro JasperReports API' which I cannot locate to download and evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

supposing that you are a paying customer, since HTML5 charts are PRO only, I highly suggest you to contact the Technical Support. They will provide you all the info.
Some details must be set, like property for license location and others related to HTML5 configuration.

Regards,
Massimo.

P.S: you could also try to open a ticket on the JasperReports tracker asking them to detail the linked wiki article.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We want to evaluate before we proceed purchasing.

I am aware of generating html 5 charts either from jasperstudio pro and jasperserver pro. But what I am looking for is, can I use jasperreports pro library to generate the reports independently ?

Comment: Yes it's possible to use it from "command line" let's say. I suggest you to open a ticket for documentation info into the JR tracker. What is needed is an overview of the properties to be set for this task.